# Алгоритм генерации случайных координат в двумерной плоскости

Tags: алгоритм, случайные-числа, генерация-случайных-данных

Какой можно придумать алгоритм генерации случайных неповторяющихся координат на сетке `width` и `height` размера, с `range` - расстоянием между ними и `count` количеством?
То есть чтобы результат был примерно следующим:
`height = 10, width = 9 count = 3 range = 2`

```
           или
.........      .........
.........      .........
....C....      .........
.........      .........
.........      .........
.C.......      .........
.........      .......C.
.......C.      ....C....
.........      .........
.........      ......C..
```

Comment: Придумываете функцию вычисления расстояния между точками, генерите случайные координаты и проверяете их с каждой из уже имеющихся точек, чтобы расстояние было как нужно. И так пока не будет нужное число точек. В чем проблема?

Comment: с каждой проверять - это очень трудоемкий процесс, если будет поле 10000х10000 - генерация будет долгая, нужно чтобы сразу не повторялись

Comment: Тогда функция нахождения координат на расстоянии X от заданной и проверяете что ни в одной из них нет точки.

Comment: Это надо проверять по кругу и плюс основной мой страх - то, что при маленьком поле может быть бесконечный цикл. Если не будет свободного места для установки точки

Comment: Зубов бояться... Сделайте отдельно проверку что число допустимых точек больше числа искомых. В общем, не вижу ни одной серьезной проблемы.

Comment: В такой постановке задача, по-моему, не имеет простого решения, сама по себе генерация уникальных координат тут очень простая, но вот именно проверка расстояния всё портит. На большом поле, которое в виде матрицы не влезет в память, придётся использовать более хитрые структуры. На ум приходят только квадродеревья. Второе решение - сгенерировать хоть какие-то уникальные точки, затем удалить те, что слишком близко, догенерировать ещё точек, снова удалить - и т. д., надеясь, что процесс однажды завершится (хотя он не обязан завершаться при такой постановке).

Comment: Можно нагенерировать случайно, потом проверить расстояния, если какая-то точка слишком близко к другой - отодвинуть точку дальше. В общем случае - да, это может быть нерешаемой задачей. Поэтому стоит добавить ограничение на количество итераций, после которых алгоритм скажет "не смог".

Comment: точное расстояние тут не имеет смысла. Если оно целое, то такое возможно практически только для очень небольшого набора точек - на одной горизонтали и вертикали, либо в 8-ми точках вокруг другой - для расстояний , являющимися точными квадратами сумм квадратов - теорема пифагора (например треугольник с катетами 3 и 4 имеет гипотенузу 5 ) . Если расстояние не целое, тогда вообще невозможно его точно указать (как корень из 2 например).
Получается - применимо расстояние в каких-то пределах. Это нужно учитывать при решении

Comment: Если параметр 'расстояние' - означает - 'не ближе чем' , то при определении очередной точки - нужно 'заштриховывать' вокруг этой точки круг с радиусом равным этому расстоянию, куда уже запрещено класть следующие точки. - Выключать из общего пространства эту область

Comment: Какое распределение точек нужно Вам? Неважно? Главное, чтобы точки были на расстоянии r и их было заданное число? А если генерацию точек сделать на CUDA тупым перебором, как предалагал @Herrgott. Но опять же, замечу, что это будет сомнительное распределение. Если бы Вы привели задачу, можно было бы сказать поточнее, что, действительно, Вам подойдёт.

Answer (score 5):

Двумерную сетку можно вытянуть в одномерный массив:

```
x = i * width + j
```

и соответственно вернуться к двумерной сетке:

```
i = floor(x / width)
j = x - width * i
```

То есть задача сводится к генерации не повторяющихся индексов от `0` до `width*height-1`:

1. Создаем массив `x` длиной `N = width*height`, заполняем его числами от 0 до `width*height-1`.
2. Берем случайное число `n` в диапазоне от `0` до `N-1`
3. x[n] превращаем в пару `(i,j)`
4. Ставим `x[n]` в конец массива (меняем его местами с `x[N-1]`)
5. Уменьшаем N на 1.
6. Повторяем начиная с шага 2.

Comment: Я уже почти сделал, спасибо. И спасибо за формулы перевода из одномерного в двухмерный, не знал. Мне же еще надо чтобы между ними было расстояние. Я сделал так, что при генерации принимает параметры `count` `range`. Через недельку будет готовый код

Comment: И что кстати значит переменная floor?

Comment: @Hergott, floor - целая часть числа

Comment: А точно - функция, забыл совсем

Answer (score 3):

Думал, думал и наконец придумал и отладил алгоритм.
У меня проверяется расстояние по ромбовидному принципу

---

`range = 3`

`....o....`
`...ooo...`
`..ooooo..`
`.oooXooo.`
`..ooooo..`
`...ooo...`
`....o....`

---

1. Создаем одномерный `boolean` массив.
2. Забиваем массив значениями `true` (Если `true` - то место свободно)
3. Создаем случайную координату в пределах поля (Для координат я использовал свой класс `Coordinate`. В нем я определил лишь два поля. X и Y)
4. Проверяем, доступна ли координата. (Я использовал функцию `GetAddress`)

   - Если доступна (`true`), генерируем координаты вокруг этой точки (Тут я пользовался функцией `GetDiamondAreaCoordinates`, но можно и любую другую вашу. Например квадратная область или круглая) и проверяем итератором валидны ли точки.
   - Если не доступна возвращаемся к пункту 3.
5. Если каждая точка области не за пределами поля, в `boolean` массив через функцию `GetAddress` забиваем false.

   - Если за пределами, то продолжаем цикл.

---

```
public Coordinate[] GetDiamondAreaCoordinates(Coordinate coordinate, int range) {
    ArrayList<Coordinate> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();

    int offsetHeight = 0, offsetWidth = range;
    int currentX = coordinate.getLeft();
    int currentY = coordinate.getTop();
    int localIterator = 0;
    for (int i = currentX-range; i < currentX+range+1; i++) {
    for (int j = currentY-offsetHeight; j < currentY+offsetHeight+1; j++) {
                coordinates.add(new Coordinate(i, j));
            }
            offsetWidth --;
            offsetHeight += (currentX-offsetWidth <= currentX)? 1 : -1;
        }
        Coordinate[] resultCoords = coordinates.toArray(new Coordinate[coordinates.size()]);
        return resultCoords;
    }
```

---

```
private int getAddress(int top, int left) {
    int index = top*width+left;
    if (index >= 0 && index < width*height)
        return index;
    return -1;
}
```